# Indexing ranges with where() in Python arrays

Tags: python, indexing, range, where-clause

I have an array of numbers called data, and I want to slice it to get only the numbers between a lower limit ll and an upper limit ul. The way I've been creating indices like this is:

```
index1 = where(data>ll)
data2 = data[index1]
index2 = where(data2<ul)
data3 = data2[index2]
```

Is there a less clumsy and wasteful way to do this, with where or another command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite understand your question, if you just want to retrieve numbers in a range, here is a solution.

If `data = [3,5,9,1,34,11,8]`,

```
[a for a in data if 1 < a < 10]
```

will get `[3,5,9,8]`

Comment: Edit: Wait, I misread this initially. This should work for my purposes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`where` is not any function in python. To get numbers between limits, use comprehension

```
[i for i in data if ll < i < ul]
```

or use `filter`:

```
filter(lambda x: ll < x < ul, data)
```